# Axios Refresh Token Infinite Loop - Multiple Requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, refresh-token

I have looked the other questions about this problem but I could not fix it.  I have a **get request** restriction for the refresh and access token renewal methods and there will be **multiple requests** in a page. Furthermore I have a **different access-token/refresh token usage** in our system.

**UPDATE:** Infinite loop issue is handled by creating an axios instance in the main instance. Now, I encounter a **request cancellation** problem often and couldn't solve it. After a request, access-token request is made but it is cancelled. I don't know why.

Below you can see the sequence diagrams:

So far, sometimes it works cursory, a request -> 401 access token expired error -> renew access token in interceptor and write it to localStorage -> same request resolves 200

But most of the time this happens and it continues with 401 loop for access-token:

Note: At the beginning of the access-token loop I get 401 including the "Staff not found" error description which means that in our system the renewed token is not included in the incoming non-token request(expired token is included in header). Normally the error description of the 401 error for non-token requests is "Token expired".

Possible noob question: How is it possible to have only one preflight and two xhr for a request?

Here is my service.js code:

```
 const sendRequest = async (options) => {
  let requestOptions = {
    ...    // includes the method, data etc.
    if (options.hasOwnProperty("token")) {
        requestOptions.headers = 
          Object.assign(requestOptions.headers, {
          Authorization: RequestOptionConstants.AUTHORIZATION + 
          options.token,
    });
   }
  
 return await axios(
  options.url, //  includes the api url
  requestOptions,    
  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {   
      return response;
    },
    async (error) => {
      const originalConfig = error.config;

    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalConfig._retry) {
      originalConfig._retry = true;

      let refreshToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
        .refreshToken;

      // Check for refresh token expiration

      if (jwtDecode(refreshToken).exp < new Date().getTime()) {  
        logout();                  
      }.       

      await axios
        .get(ApiConstants.GET_ACCESS_TOKEN, {
          headers: {
            Authorization:
              "Bearer " +
              JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).refreshToken,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.status === 200) {
            const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    

            originalConfig.headers["Authorization"] =
              "Bearer " + res.data.accessToken;

            user.accessToken = res.data.accessToken;

            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));

            if (res.data.isRefreshTokenInRenewalPeriod) {
              getRefreshToken(originalConfig);
            }

            return axios(originalConfig);
          }
        });
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
))
   .then(handleResponse, (error) => Promise.reject(error))
   .then((data) => {
    return data;
   });
};

const handleResponse = (response) => {
  const data = response.data;
  if (!data?.result?.success ?? false) {
    const error = data.result;
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }

 return data;
};

function logout() {
  localStorage.removeItem("user");
  window.location.reload();
}

const getRefreshToken = () => {
  axios
    .get(ApiConstants.GET_REFRESH_TOKEN, {
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          "Bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).refreshToken,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
        user.refreshToken = res.data.refreshToken;
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
        return axios();
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Actually I tried "return new Promise" approach from [Queue approach](https://gist.github.com/Godofbrowser/bf118322301af3fc334437c683887c5f) .

The Queue approach solved the infinite loop problem but I still encounter a 401 error with description 'staff not found' while renewing the refresh token this time.  How can I solve the infinite loop problem of the async await approach?

**SOLVED:** I solved this problem with defining two other axios instances for accessToken and refreshToken and calling them in a sequence. Images are deleted because of the confidentiality.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with axios.interceptors.response.eject() yet? It will help disable the interceptor when API called and re-enable it after. Example:

```
if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalConfig._retry) {
  originalConfig._retry = true;

  **// Add axios interceptors eject to avoid loop
  axios.interceptors.response.eject();**

  let refreshToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
    .refreshToken;

  // Check for refresh token expiration

  if (jwtDecode(refreshToken).exp < new Date().getTime()) {  
    logout();                  
  }
....
```